# Tuning Performance of Large Oracle SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, plsql

#### Introduction

Hi Everyone, I am a bit of an Oracle SQL novice coming mostly from Python. I have a large procedure that I will outline below with an example. This procedure is taking upwards of 5 minutes to process 500 records and essentially hangs after 750 records. So the runtime is essentially exponentially increasing.

#### SQL

The general overview of the procedure is made up of two select blocks selecting data from two different sources. These blocks are wrapped inside of a larger select statement that filters and matches records and selects the remainder:

For example:

```
SELECT DISINCT
  *matched sales*
FROM
  (SELECT 
    *direct sales info from db1*
  FROM
    DB1
  WHERE
    sales_code = 'DIRECT') a
  
  db2.prod,
  db2.cont,
  db2.cust, --etc
  
  (SELECT *qualified customer information
  FROM *a few DB2 tables*
  WHERE code = 'DIR') qual
  --A few more of the above inline views to get eligible cust and price

WHERE
  *DB2 product numbers, customer numbers and contract numbers are matched to eachother & above 
  views* This is where the most time is being taken up.
  --ex
  cust.cont_num = cont.cont_num
  *DB1 records matched to DB2 records*
  --ex 
  a.cont_num = cont.cont_num
```

#### Question

Ok so my issue here is the performance of the DB2 block essentially, selecting all of the different tables necessary, creating the inline views and matching all of them together. This is taking upwards of 10 minutes by itself.

As a novice, how can I tune this? Would using a temp table to store this block work so it doesn't have to do it over and over? Or should I use more inline views? Nest another select block like the first one?

#### Explain Plan

```
 OPERATION   OBJECT_NAME     OPTIONS     CARDINALITY     COST 

 SELECT STATEMENT 
         639039097   31298 
        
 HASH JOIN 
         639039097   31298 
                
 INDEX 
 CARSNG.IE_PRODID_IDX_4      FAST FULL SCAN      9184    13 
                
 HASH JOIN 
         639039097   29585 
                        
 TABLE ACCESS 
 CARSNG.UOM      FULL    6   3 
                        
 HASH JOIN 
         639039097   27881 
                                
 VIEW 
 CARSNG.index$_join$_011         8236    77 
                                        
 HASH JOIN 
               
                                                
 HASH JOIN 
               
                                                        
 INDEX 
 CARSNG.FK_PROD_IDX_4    FAST FULL SCAN      8236    20 
                                                        
 INDEX 
 CARSNG.IE_PROD_IDX_1    FAST FULL SCAN      8236    33 
                                                
 INDEX 
 CARSNG.PK_PROD      FAST FULL SCAN      8236    24 
                                
 HASH JOIN 
         639094333   26104 
                                        
 INDEX 
 CARSNG.IE_CPPT_IDX_3    FAST FULL SCAN      1254629     2473 
                                        
 NESTED LOOPS 
         634106      17709 
                                                
 HASH JOIN 
         2580    2212 
                                                        
 VIEW 
 CARSNG.index$_join$_014         24      2 
                                                                
 HASH JOIN 
               
                                                                        
 INDEX 
 CARSNG.AK_WHOAMI_IDX_1      FAST FULL SCAN      24      1 
                                                                        
 INDEX 
 CARSNG.PK_WHOAMI    FAST FULL SCAN      24      1 
                                                        
 HASH JOIN 
         2580    2210 
                                                                
 HASH JOIN 
         2589    2161 
                                                                        
 VIEW 
         2589    1690 
                                                                                
 HASH 
     GROUP BY    2589    1690 
                                                                                        
 NESTED LOOPS 
         2589    1689 
                                                                                                
 NESTED LOOPS 
         5874    1689 
                                                                                                        
 VIEW 
 SYS.VW_GBF_18       89      626 
                                                                                                                
 HASH 
     GROUP BY    89      626 
                                                                                                                        
 HASH JOIN 
     SEMI    1963    625 
                                                                                                                                
 TABLE ACCESS 
 CARSNG.CPGRP    FULL    1970    591 
                                                                                                                                
 VIEW 
 CARSNG.index$_join$_003         6415    34 
                                                                                                                                        
 HASH JOIN 
               
                                                                                                                                                
 INDEX 
 CARSNG.FK_CONT_IDX_3    FAST FULL SCAN      6415    18 
                                                                                                                                                
 INDEX 
 CARSNG.AK_CONT_IDX_1    FAST FULL SCAN      6415    25 
                                                                                                        
 INDEX 
 CARSNG.IE_CPPT_IDX_2    RANGE SCAN      66      2 
                                                                                                
 TABLE ACCESS 
 CARSNG.CPPT     BY INDEX ROWID      29      12 
                                                                        
 VIEW 
 CARSNG.index$_join$_013         43365   471 
                                                                                
 HASH JOIN 
               
                                                                                        
 HASH JOIN 
               
                                                                                                
 INDEX 
 CARSNG.PK_CPGRP     FAST FULL SCAN      43365   114 
                                                                                                
 INDEX 
 CARSNG.AK_CPGRP_IDX_4   FAST FULL SCAN      43365   192 
                                                                                        
 INDEX 
 CARSNG.IE_CPGRP_IDX_3   FAST FULL SCAN      43365   168 
                                                                
 VIEW 
 CARSNG.index$_join$_012         6415    49 
                                                                        
 HASH JOIN 
               
                                                                                
 INDEX 
 CARSNG.FK_CONT_IDX_3    FAST FULL SCAN      6415    18 
                                                                                
 INDEX 
 CARSNG.AK_CONT_IDX_3    FAST FULL SCAN      6415    44 
                                                
 INDEX 
 CARSNG.IE_ELIG_IDX_1    RANGE SCAN      246     6
```

Comment: How many rows are coming from each database?  You might try a [DRIVING_SITE hint](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10752/hintsref.htm#30401).

Comment: Please run an explain plan and post the results

Comment: Minimally, as a starting point, it's best to post the complete / valid / executable SQL, the corresponding create table statements, with indexes, along with the explain plan.

Comment: Explain plan posted for the second block itself, the problem block

Comment: That's why it's important to show the exact / complete SQL, so that cartesian products (due to missing join criteria) can be identified.  Without this detail, it's just a guessing game.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just figured this out but maybe my answer can help someone debugging in the future. I converted the DB2 selections into an inline view and that helped some. But where I was going wrong was through SELECT DISTINCT rather than SELECT, changing this saved an unreal amount of time. There was also one table that was being referenced but not matched, so I removed that.

Comment: If you are actually invoking the SQL from Python, and it returns a number of rows, then don't forget to tune `Cursor.arraysize` and `Cursor.prefetchrows`. See the cx_Oracle documentation on [Tuning Fetch Performance](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html#tuning-fetch-performance).

Answer (score 0):

Use a `select ... from ... group by <column_names>`

instead of using `distinct` for selecting columns use `group  by` for them...